# openai.error.InvalidRequestError: 'text-classification' is not one of ['fine-tune'] - 'purpose'

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model

I hope you are all doing good.

I'm having an issue with this code and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... I'm a newby in all of this so that might be a dumb question.
I get this `openai.error.InvalidRequestError: 'text-classification' is not one of ['fine-tune'] - 'purpose'`  error whenever i try to load my code, I get the same error even if i change text-classification to other things such as answers or search.

Do you have any idea why?

This is the code I tried.

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = 'My Api key'

def envoyer_fichier_texte(fichier_texte, purpose):
    response = openai.File.create(
        file=fichier_texte,
        purpose=purpose
    )
    return response['id']

dossier_texte = 'path to my files'

fichiers_texte = [fichier for fichier in os.listdir(dossier_texte) if fichier.endswith('.txt')]

purpose = "text-classification"

ids_fichiers = []

for fichier in fichiers_texte:
    chemin_fichier = os.path.join(dossier_texte, fichier)
    with open(chemin_fichier, 'r') as f:
        contenu_fichier = f.read()
    file_id = envoyer_fichier_texte(contenu_fichier, purpose)
    ids_fichiers.append(file_id)

for i, file_id in enumerate(ids_fichiers):
    print(f"ID du fichier {i+1} :", file_id)
```